# Current admin component is degraded in search service application

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, 2016

After migrating a SSA in a SP2016 farm from a production environment into a dev one by moving the databases, the SSA has taken the topology from production which has incorrect servers and means that most of the components have been degraded or unknown.

When I try to set up a new topology and activate it, I can't activate it because the admin component is down. I can't seem do much to the service because of this admin component.

Can any help to resolve this?

Name -                                           State

IndexComponent1 -                                Degraded
Cell:IndexComponent1-SP08321bdb0e10I.1.0 -       Degraded
Partition:0 -                                    Degraded
AdminComponent1 -                                Degraded
QueryProcessingComponent1 -                      Degraded
ContentProcessingComponent1 -                    Degraded
AnalyticsProcessingComponent1 -                  Degraded
AdminComponent2 -                                Unknown
QueryProcessingComponent2 -                      Unknown
ContentProcessingComponent2 -                    Unknown
AnalyticsProcessingComponent2 -                  Unknown
IndexComponent2 -                                Unknown
CrawlComponent1 -                                Active
CrawlComponent0 -                                Active

Comment: How you have migrated the contents? by detach attach method? If so whether all other site collections restored, working fine?. I am guessing something wrong happened during migration or restoration.

Comment: Read this also which might help you http://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-sharepoint/simple-guide-moving-sharepoint-content-databases-new-server

Answer (score 0):

You can see the answer for this problem at the follwing article: https://blogit.create.pt/miguelisidoro/2018/10/07/how-to-fix-a-degraded-search-index-partition-in-a-sharepoint-2013-farm/.